# R project: plot data frame

Tags: r, plot, dataframe

```
9059 2011-02-18                 2.81
9060 2011-02-21                 <NA>
9061 2011-02-22                 2.72
9062 2011-02-23                 2.75
9063 2011-02-24                 2.73
9064 2011-02-25                  2.7
9065 2011-02-28                 2.73
9066 2011-03-01                 2.75
9067 2011-03-02                 2.77
9068 2011-03-03                 2.79
9069 2011-03-04                 2.81
9070 2011-03-07                 2.81
9071 2011-03-08                 2.83
9072 2011-03-09                 2.78
9073 2011-03-10                 2.72
9074 2011-03-11                 2.76
9075 2011-03-14                 2.75
9076 2011-03-15                  2.7
```

The above is a snippet of a data frame named 'mydata'. The name of the first column is V1 and the second V2. The first column contains dates which was converted using the as.Date() function.

I want to plot this on a x-y grid with column-1 on the x-axis and column-2 on the y-axis. I've tried various combinations for hours without success.

I tried

```
> plot(mydata[,1], mydata[,2])
```

This causes the R console to hang as it appears that it is rendering something nonsensical.

Comment: Looks like you have a factor for column 2, where the data appear numeric. What does str(mydata) say about your data. If col 2 is factor, convert it to numeric: use mydata <- within(mydata, V2 <- as.numeric(as.character(V2))) and try again. Plot should have no trouble with very big vectors and plots instantly for similar data with hundreds of thousands of observations.

Answer (score 1):

This works for me (although I don't know if it produces the desired output?

```
usr <- textConnection("9059 2011-02-18                 2.81
9060 2011-02-21                 <NA>
9061 2011-02-22                 2.72
9062 2011-02-23                 2.75
9063 2011-02-24                 2.73
9064 2011-02-25                  2.7
9065 2011-02-28                 2.73
9066 2011-03-01                 2.75
9067 2011-03-02                 2.77
9068 2011-03-03                 2.79
9069 2011-03-04                 2.81
9070 2011-03-07                 2.81
9071 2011-03-08                 2.83
9072 2011-03-09                 2.78
9073 2011-03-10                 2.72
9074 2011-03-11                 2.76
9075 2011-03-14                 2.75
9076 2011-03-15                  2.7")

usr <- read.table(usr, header = FALSE)[-1] #remove the first column

with(usr, plot(V3 ~ V2))
```

Comment: Thanks Roman! I tried 'with(dat, plot(V2 ~V1)) but that also fails. What I want to do is such a simple plot. I can do this in excel in 20 seconds but I don't want to use excel because it is garbage. :-)

Comment: How big is mydata? what does dim(mydata) say? What if you just try the first ten rows with plot(mydata[1:10,1],mydata[1:10,2]) ? What does summary(mydata) do? Can you plot anything (say, with plot(runif(100)))?

Comment: Once I load the data using read.zoo (see above) I run the following:

>length(sprd)
[1] 9088

I can plot it but now I have a situation where the x-axis labels are every 10 years. My data represents the interest rate spread between the 2 and 10 year US treasury bonds going back to 1976. I want the x-axis label to be quarterly. Any idea how I could achieve this? I tried 


> plot(as.yearqtr(sprd), sprd, type='l')
Error in if (del == 0 && to == 0) return(to) : 
  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed

Comment: Are you sure you had a clean workspace and tried my example _verbatim_? What does `str(your.object)` say?

Answer (score 1):

I got it to work doing the following:

```
> x2 <- read.zoo("2_yr_tsy_rate.txt", format="%m/%d/%Y", sep=",", na.strings="ND")
>
> x10 <- read.zoo("10_yr_tsy_rate.txt", format="%m/%d/%Y", sep=",", na.strings="ND")
>
> sprd <- x10 - x2
>
> plot(sprd)
```

this worked...   but if I load the data using read.csv and try to change the data object it is a nightmare.

Now I have another problem. The plot works but the x-axis label reported in years every 10 years. My data is the interest rate spread going back to 1976. I would like the x-axis label to be quarterly. I tried various things including the following but got errors.

```
> plot(as.yearqtr(sprd), sprd, type='l')
Error in if (del == 0 && to == 0) return(to) : 
  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
```

This is the output of str(my object)

```
> str(sprd)
‘zoo’ series from 1976-06-01 to 2011-03-31
  Data: num [1:9088] 0.68 0.71 0.7 0.77 0.79 0.79 0.82 0.86 0.83 0.83 ...
  Index: Class 'Date'  num [1:9088] 2343 2344 2345 2346 2349 ...
>
```

Comment: Try wrapping this as a standalone question. Provide a reproducible example.